# Is there a library that can save data as file，but the same usage with a log library？

Tags: library, c++, key-value-store

I am a C++ beginner. These days I study [caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) and want to save some intermediate state and variables as files. Therefore I can locate the problems when

bug occurs. I have searched and found that some serialization libraries such as [boost::serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) and [hps](https://github.com/jl2922/hps) that may solve my problem. But it needs either to extra link or to modify the existing code. So I want to know if there is a library, like LOG libraries, that can save those data as binary data file, just use operater '<<' and can set a switch variable in order to facilitate turn on or off when needed. thank you very much.